# Using User Control inside Listbox or Listview on WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, user-controls

So ive created a user control that looks like this

[image]

It has some labels and a picturebox on it. What i want to do its to use this control inside a ListBox or Listview using the User control representation inside the list.
I now that i can add the items to the listbox as:

listbox1.items.add(usercontrol1);

And before this I was using the listbox as:

```
private void OwnerList_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the item's JourneyPackage that its about to be drawn.
        ListBox listbox = sender as ListBox;
        Vehicle vehicle = (Vehicle)listbox.Items[e.Index];

        e.DrawBackground();

        //Call the CustomDraw method for the JourneyPackage class.
        vehicle.DrawItemResume(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, this.Font);
    }
```

But this was a hard task as you have to use the Graphics class to draw.

So i decided to create an user control and i would like to make a listbox or listview of them, and be able to see a list of image as the one I post.
I was using the property Drawmode from listbox  as OwnerDrawVariable but im not sure if that could be the solution.

Comment: You can use a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` or `Panel` and add multiple instance of that user control to it.

Comment: Drawing the uc will not make it work. ListBox or ListView is not made for hosting other controls. FlowLayoutPanel is.

Comment: Ok. Ill use the tableLayOut or the FlowPanelLayOut thanks both